# How can I set a fix phone number in an Android app

Tags: android, sms

I am making an app that handles SMS messaging and I'd like that as well as allowing the user to type in the number they want the SMS sent to, for a fixed number to be there already so that the SMS gets sent there too. This is the XML of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Enter the phone number of recipient"
    />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="Message"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:gravity="top"         
        />          
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send SMS"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my Java code, also I'm using some deprecated classes that I intend to change but haven't done so so far any recommendation on those is appreaciated as well =)

```
public class SMS extends Activity {
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){                
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

  //---sends an SMS message to another device---
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At your main.xml try to add this in EditText

```
    android:text="your desired number"
    android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

if add

```
android:text="contact number"
```

when run the application, user can change the contact number also. This method cant fix the number too.

Answer (score 0):

In the  part, add default text using android:text="MOBILE_NUMBER". In your case it will be like,

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
      android:text="MOBILE_NUMBER"

    />
```

On clicking on the field, your default number will be there. Depending on your use, you can clear the field on clicking giving the user to enter his number. Define a onClick function and clear the text before taking input :)

Good luck,
Siddu